# Using google maps to find free WiFi android programing

Tags: android, google-maps, location, wifi, finder

i want to make application for find WiFi spots from around the world by google map.

i can make application for show google map , show current location, mark location and etc...

but now i found this link in google play and i'm interesting:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jiwire.android.finder&hl=en
or
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.wifimap.wifimap&hl=en

how can i make application like this ?

just I want a brief description about that.

sorry for bad type English .

Best Regards

Comment: Welcome from SO. This is not a coding service site. Just visit [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page for more info about this.

Comment: Sir, I don't want to give code , just i want a little discretion about how make like that application.

Comment: So, you should try many other side from internet using GOOGLE. After that if you found any other problem with your code, we can solve together. So, find any other reference site for you.